# Can vector be resized bidirectionally?

Tags: c++, vector

Is there any function to resize a vector in both directions?Can we manipulate the pointer or the element from where it starts adding new empty elements?

Comment: May be should you use `std::deque<T>` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at [some reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to study the interface of `std::vector`? That's something you should probably do before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is the entire interface of `std::vector`. It makes it very obvious there's no direct way to do what you ask, although you can `reserve` and then `insert(begin,...)` if you *really* want to (it has linear complexity, so is usually avoided).

The usual advice would be to use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead, since it's specifically designed for this operation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can insert elements to the front of the vector using `insert`:

```
vec.insert(vec.begin(), numer_of_elements_to_insert, {});
```

Note, however, that front-inserting into a vector is very inefficient, because it will require moving all the current elements in the vector past the newly inserted ones. If you need a double-ended container, look into `std::deque`.